# Start selenium remotly

Tags: linux, selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, debian-stretch

I have a Debian 9 server 
I installed over it a selenium docker grid (hub + nodes)

```
$ docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --name selenium-hub selenium/hub:3.4.0
$ docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-chrome:3.4.0
$ docker run -d --link selenium-hub:hub selenium/node-firefox:3.4.0
```

and a selenium standalone docker

What I don' t understand is how do we launch the scenarios written in PHP or Java or them as for example the grid I have access it locally, such as typing http://localhost:4444/grid/console

but as I am having a domain name already over the server (www.mydomain.com)
Should I make a virtual server to access it? by short, how do I can access to the selenium dockers to run the tests

thanks

Comment: Hi. Its not clear to me if you are willing to run tests (since you mention scenarios) or just automated browsing. Some clarification about your goal may come in handy.

Comment: Hi @alariva, yes, i would like to run the tests ( written actually in php, that i may move to java later on)